# How to check if user owns a record with Entrust?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, entrust

I want to allow users to CRUD only posts they own. I would like not to create a new middleware, but to leverage the existing ones instead. So, Can Entrust's default middlewares be extended to fit this purpose?

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('role:blogger|owner'); // <-- implement additional logic in here
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you ever had an answer/solution that is not here? I am facing a similar problem and I am thinking about moving to the standard Laravel authorization now that it is available...

Comment: As far as I remember, I haven't found any straightforward way to deal with the issue using Entrust

Answer (score 0):

```
 @if (Auth::id() === $user->id){
     Edit
    }
```

If you have defined in your `Kernel.php`

`protected $routeMiddleware = [
'auth' => '...'
]`

In your construct:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['create']]);
}
```

using eloquent along with Entrust:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles' => function($q){
$q->where('name', 'my-user-role')
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do the checking inside middleware

Comment: @AlexanderLomia  Just updated the answer, not sure if that's what you looking for.

Comment: I just want to check for user's role (**this is done by Entrust's default middleware**) && check if user owns a post he's trying to modify (**this is not**)

Comment: Sorry, may b I m not able to help you out, but i updated the answer using eloquent along with Entrust, which I have used previously. I am also waiting for an answer - something new to learn :)